# "Search Service Application" no longer works

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hope you can help again.

In short, about 3 months ago I had created a "Search Service Application". It worked.

NOTE: Our SaherPoint 2016 is on the same server as our TFS 2018.

While I was away on vacation, there was an update done to the TFS 2018 databases. After that, the "SEARCH" in SharePoint stopped working. Don't ask me why. I have to clue. Coincidence? Maybe.

Problem is that I have tried everything to fix it. I even deleted the whole "Search Service Application" in Central Admin and nothing doing. This the error I get.

**Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea what else I can try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the services and make sure that "SharePoint Search Host Controller" and "SharePoint Server Search" are running.

Comment: Both are Running. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Everyone. Sorry for the very late reply.

Well, the only thing that worked for me is to delete the Search Service Application and all it's Databasses and Info and start from scratch, asfter the third time. 

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below :

1. Clear SharePoint config cache, then restart timer service, then restart the search and search host services.
2. Check the firewall and network connectivity between SQL server and your search service application server.

3.Ask your SQL admin check the stability of SQL availability group.. if the SQL availability group does not work properly or not stable we will face this kind of issue and this AG group occurs when network is not up to the standard.

4.Try restarting SQL service.

Answer (score 0):

1.Checked extra space in Environment variable i.e. PSModulePath – No space exists.

2.Checked the Managed Metadata Service and user permission

3.Checked the Health and Usage Services and user permission

4.Re-configured the Health and Usage Services.

5.Window Service in Application Server or  WFE is running fine with same account & Re-started the service in all server also.
  Window Services :- SharePoint  Search Host Controller & SharePoint Server Search 15

You can refer to these other similar situations:
https://manojmittalblogs.blogspot.com/2016/01/unable-to-retrieve-topology-component.html
https://www.cloudsecuritea.com/2015/03/sharepoint-unable-to-retrieve-topology-component-health-states/

If the problem persists, check uls log to see if there is any relevant error information.